# What is the %TEMP% folder when running azure startup tasks from a worker role?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm running a startup task for an azure worker role which is part of an Azure cloud service.

The startup task is writing a log file to `%TEMP%`.

I'm connecting to via remote dekstop to the role machine and I want to take a look at that log, by browsing to it using windows explorer.

What is the path for of that `%TEMP%` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's here:
`C:\Resources\temp\<someGuid>.<RoleName>\RoleTemp`

Comment: This is the wrong way to get it, you should reach out to the role environment and ask for the temp folder that you configured in one of the cloud service config files. That is the only safe way to do it, the internals of cloud services could change or be deployed differently.

Comment: @AranMulholland the question doesn't refer to coding time where i can reach out to role environment. The scenario is that i have a service already running and i want to look at the logs of the startup task. Obviously it's an implementation detail that can change, but it works for now :)

Comment: Fair enough if you're just manually looking then all is well, long time between drinks to comment on that though :)